# Is there a way to send a Bootstrap Datepicker value from one component to another?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using Bootrap on my Angular Application and it is divided like this

This is my **Datepicker.html** file

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
             name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my **Datepicker**.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDateStruct, NgbCalendar} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-basic',
  templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./datepicker.component.css']
})
export class DatepickerComponent implements OnInit {
  model: NgbDateStruct;
  date: {year: number, month: number};
  constructor(private calendar: NgbCalendar) {
  }
  selectToday() {
    this.model = this.calendar.getToday();
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

And my goal is to get the selected date from my datepicker component and send it of to my dayoverview component

**Dayoverview**.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ɵangular_packages_core_testing_testing_a } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { PATIENTS } from './dummypatientdata';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-dayoverview',
  templateUrl: './dayoverview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dayoverview.component.css']
})
export class DayoverviewComponent implements OnInit {
patients = PATIENTS;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

The Datepicker is an child component of the day overview.

Comment: What is the relation between the two components?

Comment: The datepicker is an child of the dayoverview component @LeBavarois

Answer (score 0):

If Datepicker is a child component of Dayoverview component you should use an EventEmitter in the child component and bind to that in the parent component.

An example can be found in the Angular documentation:
https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event